# need help regarding this error: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm learning python so I am pretty new to it.
I've been working on a class assignment and iv'e been facing some error, such as the one in the title.

This is my code:

```
import random

def getWORDS(filename):         
   f = open(filename, 'r')
   templist = []
   for line in f:
        templist.append(line.split("\n"))
   return tuple(templist)


articles = getWORDS("articles.txt")
nouns = getWORDS("nouns.txt")
verbs = getWORDS("verbs.txt")
prepositions = getWORDS("prepositions.txt")

def sentence():
    return nounphrase() + " " + verbphrase()

def nounphrase():
    return random.choice(articles) + " " + random.choice(nouns)

def verbphrase():
    return random.choice(verbs) + " " + nounphrase() + " " +  \
           prepositionalphrase()

def prepositionalphrase():
    return random.choice(prepositions) + " " + nounphrase()
def main():
    number = int(input("enter the number of sentences: "))
    for count in range(number):
        print(sentence())
main()
```

However, whenever I run it I get an this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list.
```

Now, I know there are tons of question like this but I tried a lot of time, I am not able to fix it, I'm new to programming so I've been learning the basics since last week.

Thank you

Comment: how the data is stored in your file? if it is one word per line then  you can use `return tuple(f.read().split('\n'))` no need to use for loop

Comment: In `getWORDS`, use `extend` instead of `append`. The other (better) option is `templist.append(line.split("\n")[0])` although it might cause errors on empty lines

Comment: Providing the entire error trace, rather than just the final part, would make it much easier to help you. In fact, if you examine the trace, you can see exactly where the error occurs. Also - **capitals**, they make the difference between helping your uncle Jack off a horse, and helping your uncle jack off a horse.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've modified the function slightly - it'll fetch every words into a `tuple`. Use `with` to open the files - it will close the pointer once the values have been fetched.

I hope this will work for you!

```
def getWORDS(filename):  
    result = []       
    with open(filename) as f:
        file = f.read()
        texts = file.splitlines()

        for line in texts:
            result.append(line)
    return tuple(result)
```

Comment: hi, thank you, but I am getting this result : https://imgur.com/yLJ4f6p

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
templist.append(line.split("\n"))
```

`split()` will return a list that is then appended to templist.  If you're wanting to remove the newline character from the end of the line use `rstrip()` as this will return a string.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a file, you should use the `read()` method:

```
file = f.read()
```

To split the file to lines and add to a list, you first split, then append line by line.

```
file = f.read()
lines = file.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    templist.append(line)
```

In your case, you are using the list of lines as-is, so I would write:

```
file = f.read()
templist = file.split("\n")
```

**Edit 1:**

Another useful tool when working with files is `f.readline()`, which returns the first line when calling it for the first time, second when calling it once again... third... and so on, although the previous ways I showed would be more efficient here.

**Edit 2:**

When you are done using the file, use the `close()` method, or start using the file with a `with ... as` method which closes the file at the end of the code block.

Code example using `with ... as` (The best written code in this answer):

```
def getWORDS(filename):         
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        file = f.read()
        templist = file.split("\n")
    return tuple(templist)
```

Code example using `close()`:

```
def getWORDS(filename):         
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    file = f.read()
    templist = file.split("\n")
    f.close()
    return tuple(templist)
```

Comment: thank you :) , when i run the program and i say to print 3 sentence i get 3 lines of 3 sentence instead of just 3 sentence. here a screen : https://imgur.com/pApBzjf

Comment: sorry for not specifying, the first program simply generates the sentence. what I am working  on should input the vocabulary from a set of text files at start up, generating the same result as the first program. the issue is that the result is just a print of the text file content, instead of using it to generate random sentence, and it prints the sentence multiple time instead of just 3 times as given number,     use this screenshot as it should explain it better : https://imgur.com/acoywgN

Comment: There are a few mistakes to be addressed. First is the use of "/n" instead of "\n" which was my mistake and I will edit my post to fix it. Second is that you used "line in f", which python does not understand. You need to use "line in file", as file is the "read" version of f.

Comment: Third is that you used two methods of creating the templist, resulting in the list including twice the same information (if the previous mistakes were to be fixed). Fourth, the f.close() is in the "for loop", making the program request closing the file many times. Erase the for loop and the next line, correct the indentation for f.close(), and you are done. (Although I advise you to use the code I wrote with the "with...as")

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write the full code.
(fixed file opening and reading + fixed capitalization)

```
import random

def getWORDS(filename):         
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        file = f.read()
        templist = file.split("\n")
    return tuple(templist)

articles = getWORDS("articles.txt")
nouns = getWORDS("nouns.txt")
verbs = getWORDS("verbs.txt")
prepositions = getWORDS("prepositions.txt")

def sentence():
    sentence = nounphrase() + " " + verbphrase()
    sentence = sentence.split(" ")
    sentence[0] = sentence[0].capitalize()
    sentence = " ".join(sentence)
    return sentence

def nounphrase():
    return random.choice(articles).lower() + " " + random.choice(nouns).capitalize()

def verbphrase():
    return random.choice(verbs).lower() + " " + nounphrase() + " " +  \
           prepositionalphrase()

def prepositionalphrase():
    return random.choice(prepositions).lower() + " " + nounphrase()
def main():
    number = int(input("enter the number of sentences: "))
    for count in range(number):
        print(sentence())
main()
```